# Send additional http headers with Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a few static pages served with Express.JS. The setup is easy:

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "StaticPages")));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

I want the response to include an addittional http header (**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:***). Where should it be placed?
I tried the below sample, but of course the header appears only on the default page:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: For those looking for how to set a custom header on a route and `res.setHeader` is not defined, use `res.set` or `res.header`. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> I tried the below sample, but of course the header appears only on the default page

Yes, that is because you defined it just for the `GET /` route and not for the other paths. You should use a middleware instead.

If you wish to set the header for all requests:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return next();
  });
  app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "StaticPages")));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

If you just want to do it for the static folders, there is no general method. You can probably change the express.static(which comes from [connect.static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)). Another way to do it is to match urls and set the header if the url is matched.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var matchUrl = '/StaticFolder';
    if(req.url.substring(0, matchUrl.length) === matchUrl) {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
    return next();
  });
  app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "StaticPages")));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

NOTE: that the middleware need to be before the routes to make effect, in other words you can't put the middleware after the static middleware.

Comment: What about `setHeaders - Function for setting HTTP headers to serve with the file. - Function` in static http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

Comment: You can add a handler _after_ the static middleware that sets the header without the url substring match, instead of using `app.use` ... less overhead

Answer (score 5):

Another way :

```
app.use(express.static(
    path.join(application_root, "StaticPages"),
    {
        setHeaders: (res) => {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        }
    }
))
```