# Set correct content type for JSON requests in express app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm very new to node and trying to set up a simple backend solution to handle the routes in my Backbone application. Right now I'm routing everything to index.html. My problem is when I make a data request the response comes back with `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` when I need it to be `Content-Type:application/json`. I know I need to set this header somewhere but not sure where and was wondering if someone could help?

**JS**

```
 var express = require('express');
var port = 8000;

var server = express();
server.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

server.get('scripts/data/*.json', function(req, res) {
    return res.json({
        success: true
    })
});

server.get('*', function(req, res){
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it in get method

add

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

before sendFile

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

You can also use middleware:

In express you can use `express.static(root, [options])`

Where one of option can be: `setHeaders`  function

Check these links:

- [Send additional http headers with Express.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171899/send-additional-http-headers-with-express-js)
- http://expressjs.com/api.html
- http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Do I need to create a new `.get` with my api route in it then add the setHeader in there? If I add that into my current get then this changes all requests to JSON yeah?

Comment: Why not just use `res.json`?

Comment: Hey Vsevolod so you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

As pointed out in the answer above, you can pass additional parameters to `express.static`.

So, in order to serve your `*.json` files you should put this code about your `*` route:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'), {
    setHeaders: function(res) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't send file contents it will send object. Probably you would need to get file contents and then use res.json

Comment: This will either send a json or a file, or am I missing something? As I understood the OP doesn't want to send the file in the json

Comment: Hi, whats the condition?

Comment: @styler whatever you define it when you need to send json instead of a file. But I think a better approach is to have a separate routes for sending files and data. What is the use case of your route?

Comment: So I've been trying something like this:

`server.get('*', function(req, res){
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.get('scripts/data/*.json', function(req, res){
    return res.json({
        success: true
    })
});`

Comment: You need to place the more precise route (in your case the json) before the '*' route

Comment: When I move the JSON route above my response still comes back as html, updated question with latest

Comment: @styler I've updated my answer with a working route for you

Comment: Hey, this now fire the JSON request route but no data gets returned only the `{success:true}`

Comment: @styler if you want to read the file and return it's contents as json, you can read the file and return it's contents throug res.json

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin look at my very first comment

Comment: @styler modified the answer to use static.Robert yeah, true, now I get the point of OP, I've modified my answer to extend yours