# How to set Content-Type header in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am executing the following code in node.js. The code runs fine, but the tutorial tells us that :

> **Now go back and add the Content-Type header with a value of application/json and run the request again. You will get the “You sent
>   JSON” message back from the server.**

1) I am not able to understand how can I set headers for this program!

2) Also If I am running the program without setting headers, then the message 'Server requires application/json' should be displayed. I am not seeing it being displayed anywhere. Where should it be displayed?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const requireJsonContent = () => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
        res.status(400).send('Server requires application/json')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Welcome Home');
});

app.post('/', requireJsonContent(), (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('You sent JSON');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send additional http headers with Express.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171899/send-additional-http-headers-with-express-js)

Comment: how are you making the request?

Answer (score 0):

What I see In Your code is that, the function **requireJsonContent** that you defined Does not have parameters. So, you should add **(req, res, next)** as params to your function. Besides, inside it, you return a function without execution. However, I think You don't need that function, and your code should be like this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
        res.status(400).send('Server requires application/json')
    } else {
        res.send('You sent JSON');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With express 4.x, you can either use `res.set()` or `res.append()`. Read differences between both methods [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.append).